# Angular ngFor with Array inside FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, formgroups

I have this formGroup

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: [null],
      nome: [null, [Validators.maxLength(60), Validators.required]],
      cpf: [null, [Validators.required]],
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      telefone: [null, [Validators.maxLength(14)]],
      celular: [null, [Validators.maxLength(14)]],
      dataInclusao: [null],
      dataDesligado: [null],
      gruposEconomicos: [null]
    });
```

And `gruposEconomicos` is an array of objects. I want to retrieve this array in a `mat-select` but I am receiving this message

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'true' of type 'boolean'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

This is how I am trying to loop through this.form.gruposEconomicos:

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="mt-24">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="30">
    <mat-label>Grupo Econômico</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="grupoEconomicoId" (change)="handleGroupChange($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let group of form.get('gruposEconomicos').pristine" [ngValue]="group.id">{{ group.nome }}</option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I also tried with:

```html
<option *ngFor="let group of form.controls.gruposEconomicos" [ngValue]="group.id">{{ group.nome }}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<option *ngFor="let group of form.get('gruposEconomicos').value" [ngValue]="group.id">{{ group.nome }}</option>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input. It solved the error but I am not able to see the list on the selector. It returns null when accessing like this. But when I `console.log(this.form.controls.gruposEconomicos)` I can see the values

Comment: Study more about the form controls

Comment: FormControl.value will give you the value of that input be it array or string. But this.form.controls.gruposEconomicos will give you the entire FormControl object